# Difference between String.valueOf(Boolean) vs String

Tags: java

Is there a difference in any ways (i.e performance, maintainability,...etc) between:

```
String str = String.valueOf(Boolean.TRUE);
```

vs

```
String str = "true";
```

Comment: Practically no, not really any difference. But the first is more maintainable as it uses a well defined constant - avoiding typos in "tru" for example.

Comment: What made you ask this question? What is the real problem you are trying to solve? Also why skipping case like `String str = Boolean.TRUE.toString();`?

Comment: @Pshemo I was just curious in the case of having a constant which would be a better option. Both versions are essentially hard-coded constants. the second is straight forward. wasn't sure if there was an added advantage with using something like the first. Also, haven't considered using Boolean.TRUE.toString() but would work too.

Comment: The real question should be: Why do you need a boolean value as a string?

Comment: dependency is other another api i have i use to pass this extra parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String str = "true";
```

is faster because it does not involve a function call ( except they may be optimized to the same)

I also consider it easier to read.

The `valueOf` methods are good for variables.

Constant strings are better defined like this though:

```
private static final String TRUE = "true";
```

That way they are constant and can be optimized for sure.
So:

```
String str = TRUE;
```

Comment: I don't agree - especially with redefining the `Boolean.TRUE` constant in your own code.

Comment: @Boris That is not at all what that code does. It defines a constant String. Apparently that is what the OP needs for something.